# Does the size of a binary executable depend on inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, compiler-optimization

I have two scenarios, one with inheritance, and one without.

First:

```
Class A
{
    public:
    int a;
    void prnt() { cout << "class A"; }
}    
Class B: public A
{
}
```

Second:

```
Class A
{
    public:
    int a;
    void prnt() { cout << "class B"; }
}

Class B
{
    public:
    int a;
    void prnt() { cout << "class A"; }    
}
```

- Does the inheritance increase the size of executable or not?
  As in above example, in the first scenario I derived class B from A, so that B has all the data members of B. And in the second scenario I just copy pasted the code from class A to B.
- What is advisable in the above scenarios, where we know that there will be only two classes with same data members?
- Should we use inheritance, or just create two separate classes?
- And will there be any difference in the size of final executable in both scenarios?

Comment: it depends on many parameters.

Comment: Why do you ask? Do your decision based on what is the best design. Don't care if your executable will be a few bytes larger.

Comment: Inheritance is generally a question of semantics. Is optimizing for binary size incredibly important for your platform? If not, use inheritance to express an is-a relationship and don't use it otherwise.

Comment: Why dont you try? Actually a much more interesting question would be: "I have this two versions of the code and for version x the exe is bigger by y mb, why is this the case?"

Comment: Compilers are smart, and are capable of "folding" identical code functions together. Don't try to manually optimize the final binary via C/C++ code, the compiler/linker will likely just end up throwing your work away. Your code should be about correctness and maintainability.

Comment: There is too much "it depends" in order to answer this question.  By the way, the compiler can't simplify your `prnt` functions because they have different functionality.  If they used the same text like the first example, they could be combined.  The two examples are not similar enough.

Comment: @werner: actually this question is asked in the interview and the interviewer is looking for specific answer

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't worry to much about these kind of details and fully concentrate on the design that can best represent your application domain.

The real question you should ask, is whether B is really an A, i.e. everytime you use an A you could also use a B.

Nevertheless, for the sake of curiosity:

- I've compiled both versions with MSVC2013 by adding a `main()` creating an A and a B object and invoking their sole function (I used exacltly the same prnt body in the second example to compare comparable things).  In both debug and release mode, the exe file were in the end EXACTLY the same size.
- As pointed out in the comments, compiler do a pretty good job. For instance, in release mode, it inlined the code of the function invokation, resulting in the same main() machine code.  For the second version,  additional code was generated for `B::prnt()`, but apparently the linker identified the unused function and discarded it.
- Of course, with more complex code, the result might be different. Inlining will not always be possible, and functions can have small differences which make deduplication more difficult.
- As a rule of the tumb, the size of the code will depend more on the quantity of code (and copy/pasted code) that you write than on inheritance. Inheritance should in fact tend naturally to generate smaller code (especially true with older less optimized compilers), because the inheritance relation tells the compiler that it can/shall reuse the common code.

Comment: Thank you chris for you reply, It gives me lot help to think in right direction.